# "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects" when trying to use printf-style formatting

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation, typeerror

I don't see problem in here, but Python thinks different:

```
x = 3
y = 7
z = 2

print "I told to the Python, that the first variable is %d!" % x
print "Anyway, 2nd and 3rd variables sum is %d. :)" % y + z
```

I get `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`.

Why is that so? I haven't setted any variable as string... as much as I see.

Comment: Just so you know, the recommended method of doing string formatting in current versions of Python is the `str.format()` function. `"Anyway, 2nd and 3rd variables sum is {0}. :)".format(y+z)` (The `0` can be omitted in Python 2.7+, with the placeholder just being `{}` in that case.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`%` has a higher precedence than `+`, so `s % y + z` is parsed as `(s % y) + z`.

If `s` is a string, then `s % x` is a string, and `(s % y) + z` attempts to add a string (the result of `s % y`) and an integer (the value of `z`).

Answer (score 8):

You need to put parenthesis: `(y+z)`

Comment: If not python thinks you're doing ("Anyway %d" % y)+z

Comment: `%` has lower precedence than `+`, so `a % b + c` is parsed as `(a % b) + c`, while what you want is `a % (b + c)`

Comment: Because it formats string with `y` ant then tries to concatenate formatted string with `z`, which yields error, because they are of different types.

Comment: Grammar reference: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: Thanks for answers, guys! I just smell that learning Python will be so much fun for me! :))